# How do i select specific time and download quality MOD021KM data

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am trying to  download MOD021KM for net primary production estimation, and am so stuck on how to download the data and selecting the best time of a day using LAADS website. Morever which values for tile or longitude/latitude should i enter to obtain accurate geographical location for Zimbabwe?